# Detect when an ejectable device is (un)plugged in OS X

Tags: macos, volume, nsworkspace, diskarbitration

I am wondering how to be notified when a mass storage device is plugged (or unplugged) to the Mac.

Answer (score 4):

If you're writing a Cocoa app you can register for [NSWorkspace notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000391-BCIIDEAI) that fire when disks are mounted or unmounted.

At a lower level (more appropriate if you're writing a daemon or `NSWorkspace` doesn't give you enough information) you can use the [Disk Arbitration Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/DiscArbitrationFramework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002482).